# how to get a float from int

Tags: java, math

i has a int:

```
int f=1234;//or f=23 f=456 ...
```

i want to get:

```
float result=0.1234; // or 0.23 0.456 ...
```

dont useing:

```
float result = parseFloat ("0."+f);
```

what's best way to do?

thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

How about?

```
float result = f/1000.0f;
```

More generally, if you need to size the integer for various values of `f` you can do something like this:

```
int divisor;
for(divisor = 1; f / divisor > 0; divisor *= 10);
float result = (float)f/(float)divisor;
```

Or more concisely with logarithms:

```
float result = f / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(f))+1);
```

Comment: thanks, i writed comment, f maybe to f=23 f=456 ,i dont know f's length

Comment: Needs moar log, christ don't they teach math in high school anymore?

Comment: sorry for my stupid question, this solution (f/f.length*10) run speed better to parseFloat("0."+f) ?

Comment: @Zenofo: I'm sure the differences are negligible, do what makes sense to you or is the most readable...i.e. do the most maintainable thing.

Comment: Did you test `float result = f / Math.pow(10,Math.floor(Math.log10(f)));` because it fails for `1234`? Off by one?

Comment: `float result = (float) (f / Math.pow(10, Math.floor(Math.log10(f)+1)));`  but i think `parseFloat ("0."+f);` is better, thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
f/Math.pow(10,Integer.toString(f).length());
```

Find the length of the Integer by first converting it to String and using the String length() method.

- There probably are more clever ways of doing it.

__*_**EDIT****_*__*_***

```
f/Math.pow(10,Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.abs(f)+1)));
```

Handles negatives(and uses log).

Comment: f/Math.pow(10,Math.ceil(Math.log10(Math.abs(f)+1))); \\ Uses log and handles negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution works better than most suggested answers... Changed it a bit to cover negative numbers as well.

```
int f=1234;
if (f<0)
    result = -1.0f*parseFloat ("0."+(-f));
else
    result = parseFloat ("0."+f);
```

Still fails at `Integer.MIN_VALUE` though and note the loss in precision. For example:

```
int f=2147483647; //gives 
result == 0.21474837f
```

Answer (score 0):

I think he means, "how do I specify a literal float?"

```
float f = .1234f;  // Note the trailing f
```